# Converting an array of edges and vertices to a graph friedly format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have extracted the links between the wikipedia pages in an RDD which has the following format:

```
Array[(String, String)] = Array((AccessibleComputing,[Computer accessibility]), 
                      (Anarchism,[political philosophy, stateless society]))
```

Where the first string is a page (Vertex) and the second is a list of links (Edges) pointing towards other Wiki pages.

How can I convert it into, graph friendly format like that:

```
Array(
(AccessibleComputing,Computer accessibility),
(Anarchism,stateless society),
(Anarchism,political philosophy)
)
```

so that the edge is repeated for each vertex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`drop`, `split` and `flatMap`?

```
data.flatMap{case (k, v) => v.drop(1).dropRight(1).split(", ").map((k, _))}
```